# How to remove insignificant factor in negative binomial regression model?

Tags: r, regression

I'd done modeling negative binomial regression using function glm.nb() in R. But, some factor and some interaction term giving insignificant to my model. How do I remove the insignificant factor in order to get the better negative binomial model. Below showing the ouput :

```
> summary(nb) 
  Call:
  glm.nb(formula = LOS ~ patient + age + obesity + race + miscarriage + 
  primigravida + age*procedure, data = db , link = "log",    
  init.theta = 3.193556108)

   Deviance Residuals: 
   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.5905  -0.7482  -0.3547   0.1226   7.7317  

   Coefficients:
                                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
   (Intercept)                           0.992085   0.089697  11.060  < 2e-16 ***
   patient                               0.645335   0.034131  -1.435 0.331313 
   raceNon-Bumiputera                   -0.154894   0.052383  -2.957 0.003107 ** 
   ageMiddle                             0.102854   0.090392   1.138 0.255178    
   ageElder                              0.055655   0.099996   0.557 0.577815    
   obesityYes                           -0.250358   0.145008  -1.727 0.084256 .  
   miscarriageMiscarried                -0.060868   0.022096  -2.755 0.005875 ** 
   primigravidaYoung                     0.015143   0.084857   0.178 0.858366    
   primigravidamiddle                    0.231431   0.105432   2.195 0.028159 *  
   primigravidaElder                     0.348212   0.125971   2.764 0.005706 ** 
   procedureabortion                     0.316578   0.432455   2.467 0.341234
   procedurecsection                     0.014367   0.006113  -1.673 0.032131 **
   ageMiddle:procedureabortion           0.035266   0.041567  -1.451 0.034786 **
   ageElder:procedurecsection            0.658313   0.412243   2.111 0.324342
   ageMiddle:procedureabortion           0.124248   0.233214   1.353 0.143533 
   ageElder:procedurecsection            0.236575   0.034353  -1.235 0.013543 **  

   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

   (Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(3.1936) family taken to be 1)

       Null deviance: 5759.6  on 5381  degrees of freedom
   Residual deviance: 4852.7  on 5354  degrees of freedom
   AIC: 26956

   Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


          Theta:  3.1936 
      Std. Err.:  0.0899 

   2 x log-likelihood:  -26897.5170
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the programming question is here.

Comment: This question is on programming, if the question is meant to ask whether functions like `step`, `stepAIC` or `drop1` or `dropterm` work on or have an equivalent for `glm.nb` objects. However, it is probably more about statistics and as such would be better as Cross Validated. Maybe you could clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is probably: Don't. Within the non-interaction terms there are `age`and `obesity` which are not significantly different from the rest at any factor level. However, there are significant interactions with `age` as in `ageMiddle:procedureabortion`. You would not miss that one and you have a hard time explaining and understanding an interaction without the raw term itself in the model. So there is only obesity that is not significant at any facor level, but mind you, that obesity is usually easy to determine and with p around .08 it missed significance but may still be usefull within the model.

What you should check is, wheter patient is a patient-ID or truely a number.

You are taking about 28 coefficients out of far more then 5000 observations. Why do you think, you're model would be better if you leave a predictor or two out?

Comment: Actually, patient is a number of diagnosis. not a patient-ID. Regarding to my glm.nb() model, I didn't put age and obesity factor. but, when doing with some interaction term, both factor showing significant. I'm a bit confused here. Should I include raw term age and obesity in my glm.nb() model or not?

Comment: If `patient` is something like an ICD-Code then it makes no sense to multiply it by `0.1129`. If it is something measured, by all means, leave it in the model. I do not understand " I didn't put age and obesity factor." What does that mean? The interaction terms are significant, so they should stay in the model. As a general rule, keep all the factors in your models, that you build interactions with. It is very hard to understand an interaction without the pure factor.